# web server for embedded system

Tags: hiawatha

Is there anyone knows about list of web servers which is used in embedded system ??. I have used hiawatha, is there any others ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Boa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boa_%28web_server%29) was the first one I came to think of. Wikipedia has a fairly comprehensive [Comparison of lightweight web servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers).